# Javascript/jQuery auto set and update time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've created a `updateTime()` function in Javascript that works fine  in  `localhost` but doesn't in the `server`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxgn3pzm/)

**HTML/PHP :**

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
    $datestr = strtotime('now');
    $date = date("y/m/d H:i",$datestr);
?>
<span class="TA" title="<?php echo $date ?>" info="<?php echo $datestr ?>"></span>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.TA').each(function() {      
          var time = $(this).attr('info');
          updateTime(this,time);      
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.TA').each(function(index,el){  
            var time = $(el).attr('info');
            updateTime(el,time);
        });
    },15000);
});
function updateTime(el,time){
    var strTime = time;
    var nowStr = Date.now()/1000;
    var mins =  parseInt(nowStr) - parseInt(strTime);
    var re = '';

    if(mins>=0 && mins <86400)
    {
        if(mins>=0 && mins <60)
        re = 'just now';
        else
        if(mins>=60 && mins<3600)
        {
            mins = Math.floor(mins/60);
            mins = mins == 1 ? 'a':mins;
            re = mins+' min'+(mins>1 ?'s':'')+' ago';   
        }else
        if(mins>=3600 && mins<86400)
        {
            var h = Math.floor(mins/3600);
            h = h == 1 ? 'an':h;
            re = h+' hour'+(h>1 ?'s':'')+' ago';
        }
        $(el).text(re);
    }else
    $(el).text($(el).attr('title')); 
 }
```

in fact there is a difference between the `strtotime('now');` in `localhost` and `server` .

How can I improve this problem ? thanks in advance .

Comment: Am not answering to your question, but I suggest to use moment.js it may helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON[P] and access a time API:

(The code below should work perfectly, just tested it...)

```
 function getTime(zone, success) {
     var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
         ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
     window[ud]= function(o){
         success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
     };
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
         var s = document.createElement('script');
         s.type = 'text/javascript';
         s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
         return s;
     })());
 }

 getTime('GMT', function(time){
     // This is where you do whatever you want with the time:
     alert(time);
 });
```

If you want get it through php:

```
 $usersTimezone = 'Asia/Tehran';
 $date = new DateTime( 'Thu, 31 Mar 2011 02:05:59 GMT', new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone) );
 echo $date->format('y/m/d H:i');
```

Comment: thanks, but I think my problem is `php strtotime('now')`

Answer (score 1):

It probably works locally because your browser and localhost is the same machine, but the server is not, time can be different on different machines.

The time on the client machine is used by javascript but the time in the info attribute is set by the server. To overcome this problem, use only the client time (set the info attribute with javascript when the page loads e.g.) or use a time API as mentioned by KaMZaTa for both the client and the server.